# spring boot failed to start after moving code from eclipse luna to eclipse oxygen

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat7, eclipse-oxygen

the application start correctly when i use eclipse luna but when i change it to eclipse oxygen the application failed to start with this error,i try also an external tomcat but it does not work:

```
20-mars-18 10:34:47:087 ERROR main o.s.b.SpringApplication:771 - Application startup failed
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1080)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
        at org.rma.portailged.ApplicationPortailWebRunner.main(ApplicationPortailWebRunner.java:31)
```

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548810/invocation-of-init-method-failed-nested-exception-is-java-lang-incompatibleclas ?

Comment: this answer does not work

Answer (score -2):

Spring Boot works best with Eclipse Photon and Mars

Comment: Spring Boot works best with [Spring Tools Suite](https://spring.io/tools) which, at the time of writing, is at Eclipse 2019-12. That's way ahead of Photon and Mars.